# CSS grid overflowing the page when using grid items with aspect-ratio

Tags: html, css, css-grid, aspect-ratio

I have created a CSS grid layout in which grid items have `aspect-ratio: 1 / 1`. I don't know why this causing the grid to overflow the page.

Here is the code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.span-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.div {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="span-grid">
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```

I would like the grid to fit on the screen while leaving empty space on the left and right of the screen. The boxes should be exact squares.

[image: layout on higher resolution]

Comment: You can't have squares AND fill the screen without overflow since the screen is not square. You will have to clarify what behaviour you are looking for. You can have `max-height: 50vh` on the divs but they won't fill the screen - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/JjxVQBm

Comment: @Paulie_D

I want to have squares and empty space and on the left and right of the screen. I wrote about this in the post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to scale it down. You may size the parent to a max-size that would be the smallest max-size of height/width to keep your square ratio within the browser view.

Here is an example using vmin value.

```css
html {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.span-grid {
  aspect-ratio: 1; /* you can define your square here */
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  max-height: 100vmin;
  margin: auto;
}

.div {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="span-grid">
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```